# Interprete LISP en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, lisp

estoy realizando un intérprete de LISP en Python, específicamente con las operaciones aritméticas elementales (+ - * /), he logrado realizar las operaciones de expresiones como por ejemplo ( + 10 -15 2 ) o ( * 7 6 7 3 ). Ahora, para expresiones como ( + ( * ( / 8 7 ) 15 ) -2 ) no logro poder emplear lo que realicé para las expresiones anteriores, aquí el código empleado.

```
def sumalista(lista):
i=1
suma = 0
for i in lista:
    suma = suma + i
return suma

def productolista(lista):
i=1
producto=1
for i in lista:
    producto=producto*i
return producto

m=input("Introduce la s-expression:");
y=m.split()

if y[1]=="+":
  y_1=y[3:len(y)-1]
  x=list(map( float, y_1))
  print(float(y[2])+sumalista(x))
elif y[1]=="-":
  y_1=y[3:len(y)-1]
  x=list(map( float, y_1))
  print(float(y[2])-sumalista(x))
elif y[1]=="*":
  y_1=y[3:len(y)-1]
  x=list(map( float, y_1))
  print(float(y[2])*productolista(x))
elif y[1]=="/":
  y_1=y[3:len(y)-1]
  x=list(map( float, y_1))
  print(float(y[2])*1/productolista(x))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir que no logras poder emplear lo realizado anteriormente? no funciona? tira un error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según se deduce del postulado, una expresión LISP consta de un signo de operación seguido de un número indeterminado de valores y/o expresiones, todo rodeado entre paréntesis, como (+ 1 2 3), (* (+ 1 2) (+ 2 3)).

Lo primero es crear un *generador* que recibe la expresión original y nos devuelva las partes que la componen. Para simplificar el caso, la expresion debe separar cada componente con espacios.

Este generador puede retornar una cadena o un valor numérico, según sea el caso.

```
def next_token(expresion):
    """
    Generador de partes de una expresión LISP

    :param expresion: La expresión LISP, con espacios rodeando cada parte.
    :return: El siguiente token como valor numérico (si corresponde), o
    como string, como "(", ")", "+", ...
    """
    for parte in expresion.split():
        try:
            parte = float(parte)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        yield parte
```

Con eso podemos construir una función `evaluar` recursiva, que reciba este generador y retorne el valor numérico resultante.

Al encontrar la operación en la expresión, la copiamos a `operacion`. A continuación leemos el siguiente elemento de la expresión. Si es un valor numérico, lo usamos para inicializar `resultado`. Luego continuamos leyendo elementos y aplicando la operación sobre el resultado previo. Si en cualquier etapa nos encontramos con una expresión en lugar de un valor, evaluamos la expresión recursivamente.

```
def evaluar(generador):
    """ Evalua numéricamente una expresión LISP.

    :param generador: Un generador
    :return: Valor numérico.
    """
    resultado = None  # El resultado calculado
    operacion = None # La operación a realizar.

    token = next(generador)
    #   Descartar el "(" inicial.
    if token == '(':
        token = next(generador)

    #   Procesar hasta llegar al final de la expresión.
    while token != ')':
        if token == '(':
            # Convertir expresión LISP es un valor numérico
            # Caso (+ 3 (- 1 2)) donde hay dos operandos:
            # el valor 3 y la expresión (- 1 2)
            token = evaluar(generador)

        if type(token) == float:
            #   Es un valor númerico; aplicar la operación.
            if resultado is None:
                #   Primer valor numérico después de un operador.
                resultado = token
            elif operacion == '+':
                resultado += token
            elif operacion == '-':
                resultado -= token
            elif operacion == '*':
                resultado *= token
            elif operacion == '/':
                resultado /= token
        elif token in "+-*/":
            operacion = token

        token = next(generador)

    return resultado
```

**Demo**

```
tests = [
         "( + ( + 1 2 ) 3 )",
         "( + 1 ( + 3 5 ) )",
         "( + 1 4 )",
         "( +  1 2 3 4 5 )",
         " ( + ( * ( / 8 7 ) 15 ) -2 )",
         "( * 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 )"]
for test in tests:
    print(test, end=" => ")
    generador = next_token(test)
    res = evaluar(generador)
    print(res)
```

produce:

```
( + ( + 1 2 ) 3 ) => 6.0
( + 1 ( + 3 5 ) ) => 9.0
( + 1 4 ) => 5.0
( +  1 2 3 4 5 ) => 15.0
 ( + ( * ( / 8 7 ) 15 ) -2 ) => 15.142857142857142
( * 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ) => 3628800.0
```