# Archivo LISP/Python

Tags: python, lisp

Requiero ejecutar un archivo con extensión .lisp en python 3 el contenido del archivo .lisp es

```
(write ( + 1 4 7 ))
```

el cual debe arrojar la suma de los números ingresados es decir 12. Para ejecutar el archivo desde python utilizo el siguiente código

```
archivo=open('programa.lisp')
print(archivo.read())
```

Al ejecutarlo, la salida es

```
(write (+ 1 4 7 ))
```

y debería ser 12

¿Cómo puedo obtener lo que requiero?

Comment: Para ejecutar un programa Lisp necesitas construir un intérprete Lisp, un programa que lea `(write` y  ejecute la función de escribir con los argumentos que vienen a continuación `(+ 1 4 7 )`, que previamente deberas evaluar. Esta respuesta te puede dar una idea: [Interprete LISP en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409060/interprete-lisp-en-python/409085#409085)

Answer (score 2):

Este es un micro-interprete de Lisp. No tiene manejo de errores y sólo reconoce expresiones Lisp simples, de la forma `(comando arg1 arg2 ... argn).

**Implementación de los comandos**

Por cada comando Lisp habrá una función Python que lo implementa.

El formato de las funciones es simple: recibe una lista con los argumentos, y devuelve el resultado de la operación.

Estas son las definiciones para los comandos `+` y `write`:

```
"""
Implementación de comandos lisp.
Cada función implementa un comando que recibe una lista de argumentos y retorna algo.
"""
def sumar(args):  # Implementa comando '+'
    total = 0
    for valor in args:
        total += float(valor)
    return total

def escribir(args): # Implementa comando 'write'
    print(*args)
    return None
```

Los comandos validos los agrupamos en un diccionario. Su llave es el comando, su valor, la función que lo implementa:

```
"""
Tabla de comandos. Un diccionario indexado por comando lisp que entrega una función con su implementación
"""
comandos = {"+": sumar,
            "write": escribir}
```

**Tokenizador**

El script Lisp debe ser descompuesto en sus partes elementales. Este es el rol del tokenizador, que dado el programa

```
(write "El resultado es" (+  1 2 3))
```

debe dividirlo en sus partes elementales:

```
(
write
El resultado es
(
+
1
2
3
)
)
```

El tokenizador lo implementamos como un generador que recibe el nombre del archivo con el script Lisp y que retorna el siguiente token en cada invocación:

```
def sig_token(file_name):
    """
    Generador que recibe un nombre de script lisp y lo divide en tokens.

    Un token puede ser:
    - Un "(" o ")", siempre solos.
    - Una cadena conteniendo un número o nombre, como 23.4 o write.
    - Un texto arbitrario, originalmente encerrado en comillas simples o dobles. Solo
      reconoce textos simples como "Ingresa tu nombre:". El texto no lleva las cremillas.

    :param file_name: El path al script lisp.
    :return: Un token cada vez.
    """
    with open(file_name, "r") as fuente:
        for linea in fuente:
            largo = len(linea)
            i = 0
            while True and i < largo:
                inicio = i
                if linea[i] in "()":
                    i += 1
                    yield linea[inicio:i]
                elif linea[i] in "\"'":
                    i += 1
                    while i < largo and linea[i] != linea[inicio]:
                        i += 1
                    yield linea[inicio + 1: i]
                    i += 1
                else:
                    # Encontramos un número, nombre, operador, ...
                    while i < largo and not linea[i].isspace() and linea[i] not in "()":
                        i += 1
                    yield linea[inicio:i]

                # Saltar todos los blancos a la derecha del token
                while i < largo and linea[i].isspace():
                    i += 1
```

**Evaluación**

Ahora que tenemos separadas los distintos token del script Lisp, sólo resta reunir los argumentos y ejecutar los comandos.

```
def lisp(expresion):
    """
    Evalua una expresion lisp y devuelve su resultado

    Formato general de una expresión:
      (comando arg1 ... argn2)

    :param expresion: Un generador que devuelve un token a la vez.
    :return: El resultado de la evaluación
    """

    comando = next(expresion)
    if comando == "(":
        comando = next(expresion)
    # Todo lo que sigue son argumentos para el comando.
    args = []
    token = next(expresion)
    while token != ")":
        if token == "(":
            # El argumento es otra expresión, que debe ser
            # evaluada antes de incluirse con los otros
            # argumentos.
            token = lisp(expresion)
        args.append(token)
        token = next(expresion)

    # Ejecutar el comando y retornar su resultado.
    return comandos[comando](args)
```

**Demo**

*test.lisp*

```
(write "El resultado es" (+  1 2 3))
```

produce:

```
El resultado es 6.0
```